# Accessing $route.params in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, router

Looking through this documentation:
https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html

It looks like you can bind the `<router-link :to="variableName">Link Text</routerlink>` Which is pretty nifty; however, I've had some trouble trying to access route parameters inside of a component I'm trying to build.

So I use this:

```
<router-link :to="permalink">Title of thing</router-link>
```

To then direct the router view to pull the forum thread.  Using this in the router:

```
import ForumThread from './views/groupTitle/forumThreadSingle';

// Other routes...
let routes = [
    {
        path: '/groupTitle/th/:id',
        component: ForumThread,
    } 
];
```

I can see in the forumthread component that $route.params.id is being passed too it; however, when I try to access it like this:

```
console.log('The id is: ' + $route.params.id);
```

It's unable to find the params portion of the object.

VueJS is pretty new to me as well as JavaScript itself.  All the examples I've seen show the templates being inline with the router file which is something I am trying to prevent to help keep my code readable and clean.

What adjustments can I make so that I can pass properties to the template file?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show more context around your `console.log` statement. Is that in a function of a Vue instance?

Comment: What is the content of the `permalink` variable?

Comment: Inside a vue component you can simply use this.$route.params....

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If you're using the Vue Loader setup (which has `<template></template>` tags in the files), you need to use `this` to reference the $router, if you're doing so within the `<script></script>` part of the file.

```
 console.log('The id is: ' + this.$route.params.id);
```

Comment: In my case, I had to use console.log('The id is: ' + this.$route.params.id.toString());

Answer (score 39):

For and one wanting to get params in vue 3 with composition API for vue-router 4.x, it can be achieved using useRoute.

```
import {useRoute} from "vue-router";
setup(){
   const route = useRoute();
   const id = route.params.id;
}
```