# Is there a way i can get a route parameter in vue

Tags: vue.js

I am new to vuejs, i have my api in laravel having a route such as

Route::get('/get-song-details/{id}','SongsController@getSongDetails');. How do get this id in vue so that i can display only information about the selected song.

in the sample below, when i pass 1, i get information about song 1, and so on. how do i make it dynamic?

```
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            songs : []
        }
    },
    created(){
        axios.get('/api/get-song-details/1')
        .then(response => this.songs = response.data);
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Use vue-router!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing $route.params in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414918/accessing-route-params-in-vuejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asumming you are using [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/), the route component should be declared so:

```
routes: [
  { path: '/song/:id', component: Song }
]
```

then in your created method of Song component can get the id param:

```
created() {
  axios.get('/api/get-song-details/' + this.$route.params.id)
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All route params can be accessed by using `this.$route.params.paramName` in JS code or by using `$route.params.paramName` in template. `paramName` is the parameter name as defined in your router.